# Searching a keyword in a long string in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

keyword = house

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE description LIKE '%house%'
```

This query also returns records having keyword, for example, courthouse, but I want to look for house only. How do I search anywhere in the description for "house" only?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

just for more clarification ..

```
actually house, can be at 
  -  the start of the description .. "House for sale..", 
  -  can be quoted -- "house", 'house'
  -  can have exclamation .. house!!!, house!
  - others - house? etc ..
```

this is why I used %house%

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM products WHERE description rlike '[[:<:]]house[[:>:]]'

rlike is synonim for [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

[[:<:]] denotes the start of the word and the
[[:>:]] end of the word.

It works for all your requirements (case insensitive, with quoted words or words ending, or begging, with exclamation points and other non-letter characters)

Comment: can you please put some details so that I can modify accordingly, if required?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for longs strings containing the whole word?

[Search for "whole word match" in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-sql)

Comment: I think this is the solution, I posted explicit one before checking yours

Answer (score 1):

The `%` before and after will search any matching text before and after the search keyword, try this instead for exact search:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE description = 'house'
```

Comment: @astander: this is what he says: "This query also returns records having keyword, for example, courthouse, but I want to look for house only."

Comment: I dont think this is what the OP wants. *How do I search **anywhere in the description** for "house" only*

Comment: @astander: yes his question is not that clear. Let's see what exactly is he looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a space around the keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE description LIKE '% house %' OR description LIKE 'house %' OR description LIKE '% house' OR description LIKE '% house%'
```

Edit: added more options in search. The last one would allow for `house.` or `house,`, though something like `housecat` would also match. Regex would work best here. This solution came from [Astandar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144424/astander), who deleted his answer.

Comment: What if the keyword is at the end of a sentence? "I have an awesome house!"

Comment: astander's solution is better than mine, as it allows the desc to start or end with the keyword too.

Comment: @Aaron ya, just realized that. Astander has the right answer.

Comment: I think that the **REGEX** option from [@Bears will eat you] seemed like a better solution, that is why I removed my answer X-)

Comment: Ya, once I thought about punctuation I realize that was better too. So, @user187580, [@Bears will eat you] has the best answer, imo, but if you don't want to play with regex, see mine or @Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing only house means, use this

```
   SELECT * FROM products WHERE description = 'house'
```

If you want any word contain house in backside means use this,

```
   SELECT * FROM products WHERE description LIKE '%house'
```

If you want any word contain house in frontside means use this,

```
   SELECT * FROM products WHERE description LIKE 'house%'
```

If you want any word contain house in anywhere in description  means use this,

```
   SELECT * FROM products WHERE description LIKE '%house%'
```