# "Where" statement: match a single word (not substring)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL.

I have a **car** table in my database, and there is a `name` column in that table.

Suppose the `name` column of the table contain values:

```
 +----------+
 |   name   |
 +----------+
 | AAA BB   |
  ----------
 | CC D BB  |
  ----------
 | OO kk BB |
  ----------
 | PP B CC  |
  ----------
```

I would like to search the table where `name` column value **contains word** "**BB**" (not substring), What is the SQL command to achieve this ?

I know **LIKE** , but it is used to match a contained substring, not for a word match.

**P.S.**

**My table contains large data. So, I probably need a more efficient way than using LIKE**

The values in `name` column are random strings.

Please do not ask me to use **IN (...)** , because the values in that column is unpredictable.

Comment: This line of your question confuses me, "...used to match a contained substring, not for a word match."

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. I mean I would like to query in the column where the value contains the word "BB". The "LIKE" is used to search for a substring not a word. For example LIKE will return also "cccBB" which is not expected.

Answer (score 5):

Try this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE name LIKE '% BB %'
OR    name LIKE 'BB %'
OR    name LIKE '% BB'
OR    name = 'BB'
```

Note that this will not perform well if your table is large. You may also want to consider a [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) if you need better performance.

Comment: My table contains large data. So, I probably need a more efficient way than using LIKE

Comment: @Mark: Be careful, this will not match punctuation. Full-text search is a good idea though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`REGEXP operator`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM car
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]BB[[:>:]]'
```

It will match `BB` if it occurs as a single word. From the MySQL manual:

> - `[[:<:]], [[:>:]]`
>
>   These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (_).
>
>   ```
>   mysql> SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';   -> 1
>   mysql> SELECT 'a xword a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';  -> 0
>   ```

Comment: You could refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql before just copying it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit of the  meaning of [[:<:]] , or the whole regular expression?

Comment: @Dimme: I haven't copied it … I'm seeing the other question/answer for the first time.

Comment: @Dimme, you're sure knittl copied it? Please enlighten me: how can you tell?

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. Negative vote removed. @toon81 if you google the question this URL comes up first. It is a valid reason to believe that this was copied because the answer is very similar.

Comment: @Dimme: The answer was very simple. With such small entropy two questions will look similar very quickly. But when I wrote the answer, I didn't search for »mysql match single word«, but for »mysql manual regex« instead.

Comment: I am mostly concern about the performance issue, will the REGEXP be slow for performance? as my table is large.

Comment: mellon, the regex itself looks fine. it's almost 100% certainly much faster than regexing with PHP. @Dimme I guess it's a decent reason for suspecting it.