# Square bracket us in SQL statements for wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

When I use square brackets with a `%` wildcard as below MySQL does not select any records starting with a number. Many examples across the internet state this as the correct use. Any suggestions? It doesn't work for a letter (`a-d`) range either. I'm running MySQL 3.2

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lname LIKE '[0-9]%' ORDER BY lname ASC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lname LIKE '[a-d]%' ORDER BY lname ASC
```

Comment: Where did you see MySQL examples using that syntax? I don't believe it is supported and isn't mentioned in the [`LIKE` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).  A similar thing is supported by MSSQL...

Comment: MySQL does support [`REGEXP/RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) which can be used to achieve what you want.

Comment: The SQL standard only defines two wildcards for the `LIKE` operator: `%` for multiple characters and `_` for a single character. Everything else is non-standard and specific to one DBMS. MySQL's `LIKE` operator does not support any non-standard extensions as far as I know. And besides: MySQL 3.2 is definitely outdated. You should really upgrade to a DBMS from this millennium.

Answer (score 3):

Although I do not believe MySQL supports regular-expression-like character classes in `[]` with a regular `LIKE` clause (nor can I find [relevant documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)), MySQL does have a [`REGEXP/RLIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) with which you can construct a regular expression for comparable functionality.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lname REGEXP '^[0-9]' ORDER BY lname ASC
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lname REGEXP '^[a-d]' ORDER BY lname ASC
```

To build a regular expression similar to the wildcard patterns you used, start with `^` to left-anchor the pattern, and use the same character class `[0-9], [a-f]` as you proposed. You do not need to follow it by anything, because the `%` wildcard would be equivalent to a match of any zero or more characters following the initial left-anchored letter or number matched by `^[]`.

Of course, you can combine those statements with a logical `OR`, or build a regular expression which matches either case.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lname REGEXP '^[a-d]|[0-9]' ORDER BY lname ASC
```

[Here's a demonstration.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ad3a/7)

One thing to keep in mind however: [MySQL will not be able to use any index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153271/regexp-performance-compare-with-like-and) you may have on `lname` when using `REGEXP`.

*n.b. I believe [MS SQL Server supports a syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) similar to what you proposed.*

Answer (score 1):

I think in Mysql you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lname REGEXP '^[a-d]'
```

[MySql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4271/5)