# datatables + regex + serverside processing

Tags: mysql, regex, datatables

this is an [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) of the regex using datatables that I like. 
e.g. enter `^[S,A]` in the global search and tick `Treat as regex` and this gives all the Columns that Start with `A` or `S` and this is what I want to achieve.
not quiet sure how `Use smart search` works

And this is the server side processing [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

here is a basic datatables [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gpLcfkr/)

Can I combine these so that I can do a regex in datatables that works on the server side processing?

As a first I have tried something like this on my db but not sure if it can be done here before trying to do it in datatables. 
`SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee WHERE employee_name LIKE REGEXP '^[A,S]'`

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might want to change your regex to `^[AS]`. Your current regex will give results that start with a `,` as well.

Comment: Remove the `LIKE`, you only need the `REGEXP`. See [4.3.4.7 Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: @Harsh Good point. that is my lack of knowledge in regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee
WHERE employee_name LIKE REGEXP '^[A,S]'
```

This will do not give what you want, and should get a syntax error. As @Harsh Poddar said, it will also match column started with `,`, so the regexp expression is just `'^[AS]'`.

Anyway, if you want query all of columns started with `A` or `S`, it will help by followed sql;)

```
SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee
WHERE employee_name REGEXP '^[AS]'
```

This is not similiar with followed sql,

```
SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee
WHERE employee_name LIKE '%A%'
```

If you want use `LIKE`, it should be like this as least,

```
SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee
WHERE employee_name LIKE 'A%' or employee_name LIKE 'S%'
```

And if you want more character start, you need to add more `LIKE` condition in `WHERE` clause, so it seems to be more concise for you to write a query sql when you use `REGEXP`.
About performance, take a look of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153271/regexp-performance-compare-with-like-and).

Comment: ultimately I want to get it working with datatables but is `SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee
WHERE employee_name REGEXP '^[AS]'` the same as `SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee
WHERE employee_name LIKE '%A%'` or at least very similar, with the REGEXP more powerful?