# How to search an item properly using Hql in my asp.net project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, hql

My query returns searched data but it does'nt search properly

in my table values are

```
 ------------------------
       Help
 ------------------------
1    help for abcd
2    help needed before
```

my Hql query given below

```
select help from Help  help where lower(help.Subject) like lower ('%'" + searchterm + "'%')
```

when i search for "for" it returns

```
------------------------
       Help
------------------------
1    help for abcd
2    help needed before
```

I need to return only the first

```
1. help for abcd
```

ie: I need to search only the term begins with the search term

Any one please help...

Comment: If you need to search only the terms begins with the search term try   select help from Help  help where lower(help.Subject) like lower (" + searchterm + "'%')

Comment: it never works my frnd it search only the first term .it doesn't return the search result when i search for "for" or "needed" or "abcd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello frnds i got the solution which works perfectly

at first using the query

```
 select help from Help  help
```

then store the list of help in

```
 var ListofHelps
```

then

```
   foreach (var item in ListofHelps)
        {

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchterm))
          {
           var splitsearchterm = Regex.Split(searchterm, @"\s");//split search term

                var splittedsubjects = Regex.Split(item.Subject.ToUpper(), @"\s"); //Subject is to be searched
                var found = splittedsubjects.Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchterm.ToUpper()));
                int datacount = found.Count();
                if (splitsearchterm.Count() > 1 && item.Subject.ToUpper().Contains(searchterm.ToUpper()))
                {
                    datacount = 1;

                }
                if (datacount > 0)
                {
                    Helplist.Add(new HelpViewModel //Helplist is an item in HelpViewModel ie public IEnumerable<MultiSelectList> Taglists { get; set; }
                    {
                        Subject = item.Subject,
                        HelpId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Id),
                        Content = item.Content

                    });
                }

            }
            else
            {

                Helplist.Add(new HelpViewModel
                {
                    Subject = item.Subject,
                    HelpId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Id),
                    Content = item.Content

                });

            }


        }
```

It works for me .Is there any better way to do that

Answer (score 1):

This sounds Like a Word Boundary Problem. Here Is A similar question answered

[Search for "whole word match" in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql)

Sorry, I Have No Idea Why Android Wants To Capitalize All My Words.