# Compare LIKE clause with entire word

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Currently, my SQL search query use `LIKE` clause with `%some-word-to-search%` wildcards.

The problem of using percent wildcard is that it's returning all the rows which containing a part of my search param, e,g:

If I search **car** It will also show **cartoons** to me! is there any way to compare like clause only with entire words instead of part of it?

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: Put a space before and after "some-word-to-search"?

Comment: see if this discussion could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql

Comment: Do not use wildcard character. You will get exact matching of record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) that matches word boundary. For example, this will match rows where the text contains "car" as a single word, even when it's the first or last word, or adjacent to punctuation:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytext REGEXP '[[:<:]]car[[:>:]]';
```

Note that these kinds of queries require a table scan. A [full text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) can give better performance.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent way, I will accept this answer in next 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the natural language search function match():

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html