# MySql Query on parts on string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, sql-like

The name column contains items like 'John Smith', 'Elsa John Sanders', 'LilJohn Thomson', 'John'.
How can I structure a query just to return the names with John but not LilJohn.

I cannot do a LIKE '%John%' as it would return 'LilJohn Thomson'.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the same as:
[Search for "whole word match" in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql)

The approach uses a slick regular expression.

Comment: This indeed is a good link. Sometimes it seems though if all you have is a hammer, everything starts looking like a nail: Regular expressions are great but relatively slow, because they usually cannot make use of indexes. If the names are always enclosed in spaces, I don't see a need for a regular expression.

Comment: @Hazzit Good call on regular expressions being relatively slow. If names are enclosed in spaces that's a good solution ... but often the name comes at the start or end of the value. To work around that, I would check against ' ' + VALUE + ' ' .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a word is defined by a space, you can do:

```
where concat(' ', col, ' ') like '% John %'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression should find all "John"s

```
a = 'John' OR
a LIKE 'John %' OR
a LIKE '% John %' OR
a LIKE '% John'
```

Please note that some other tricks also work, but may severely hit performance, like

```
CONCAT(" ",a," ") LIKE "% John %"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try SIMILAR TO '%+John+%' using the + space wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**REGEXP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) function.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a 
WHERE a.name REGEXP '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]'
```