# mysql check if given string are in a comma separated list without FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 'string' in ('string1','string2','string3')
```

Its not given correct result find_in_set only given a exact result. If any way to get correct result without using `find_in_set`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FIND\_IN\_SET() vs IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 'string' in
>   ('string1','string2','string3');

In the above query, `string` is supposed to be a field (column) so, if you were to have this query work, it would be without single quotes `'`, like this:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE string IN
>   ('string1','string2','string3');

This will return all rows where the field `string` is exactly `string1` or `string2` or `string3`.

---

**Now, if you want to query the field `string` for values like** "string", not exactly matching, then you use the [LIKE operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp):

> SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE string LIKE '%string%';

In the above query, all 3 records containing `string1`, `string2` and `string3` will be returned.

Comment: In my case i can't use '%like%' because my strings are like ('a','aa','aaa'). So if i put like "%aa%" it returns aa,aaa

Comment: @AroInfantraj https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql